# IIS web server - enable connection from other host

Tags: iis, web, config

Completely newbie question:

How can I allow access to a web server from another host, with a configured application that is accessible from localhost?

Where are configuration files stored? Is there a registry key?

I'm coming from unix, first time looking at IIS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is access the site using the IP address of the host machine and configure the firewall on that machine to allow access on the port that the website is sitting on.

If you want to access the site via a host header instead of an IP address, there's a bit more to it. If you don't have a domain name that the IP address publicy resolves to, you can add an IP mapping in the hosts file on the client machine (located in `C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc`). Once you have that, you can edit the site bindings within IIS on the server and add a host name, which will mean you can access the site using the host name rather than the IP. If the host name resolves to the IP address of the server through DNS, you don't need to add the entry to your host file.